# how to send mails using phpmailer through yahoo SMTP?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am using phpmailer to send mails it is working with gmail but when it comes to yahoo giving the following errors

SMTP -> Error : Password not accepted from server : 530 access denied
SMTP -> Error : RSET failed
SMTP -> Error : Could not authenticate

i am using the working yahoo account.

Please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Yahoo SMTP with normal email client (e.g. Thunderbird) and see if it works then? If it works - then problem is in phpmailer, if not - maybe IP somehow landed in some spam-blacklist and Yahoo is simply rejecting all mails from it?